# BUG on mycode i spend hours dont find what the issue

Tags: php, sql

Hi please see this code,
I am using this code to update current project,
$current_project_id using the i am getting the current project to edit
I have checked the data to post variables i am getting it while doing a echo statement.
there may be some issue while i pass this to my class function using the object.

ALSO: Help appreciated, If you find some security issue on my code :)

**User Side:**

```
<?php 
    $current_project_id = (int)$_GET["pid"]; //Getting current project to Update from URL parameter.

    $currentproject = $touchObj->get_projects_by_id($current_project_id); // Using  project id to update, we are taking all project data.
?>


<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if(isset($_POST['project_name']) && isset($_POST['project_location'] )) { 

    include('inc/handleUpload.php'); // Image uplaod class
    $up->config('20000000','jpg,gif,png,pdf,txt,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,zip,rar');
    $up->upload('project_file','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'); //Server file location for upload folder.


    $project_investor_id = implode(",",$_POST["project_investor_id"]); // Our table field store data as comma seperated separated

    $project_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_name']);

    $project_location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_location']);

    $project_phase = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_phase']);

    $project_capital = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_capital']);

    $project_total = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_total']);

    $project_notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_notes']);

    $file = $up->fileInfo['fname'];



    $touchObj->update_project(
        $current_project_id,
        $project_investor_id,
        $project_name, 
        $project_location,
        $$project_phase,
        $project_capital,
        $project_total,
        $project_notes,
        $file
        );
}
else 
{

    echo '<div class="alert alert-info"><h6>Please fill datas...</h6></div>';
}

}
?>
```

**My function of this particular Class:**

```
 public function update_project($project_id, $project_investor_id, $project_name, $project_location, $project_phase, $project_capital, $project_total, $project_notes, $file){

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE project_table SET 
    project_investor_id = $project_investor_id, 
    project_name = $project_name,    
    project_location = $project_location,
    project_phase = $project_phase,
    project_capital = $project_capital,
    project_total = $project_total,
    project_notes = $project_notes,
    project_file = $file
    WHERE project_id =$project_id");

    if($result) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><h6>Project updates... Do not refresh window...</h6></div>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><b>Some error while updating the project. Please try again...</b></div>';
    }

}
```

**Result:**
Some error while updating the project. Please try again...

I am not able to update data usig this function Please reviwe it and let me know what i missed? any ideas?

Thank You very much for your valuable time

Comment: You need to add apostrophe for the values of fields having data type varchar or text.. E.g;  project_name = $project_name should be project_name = '$project_name',

Comment: Yes it works.... I just missed those :(( what a .... What about the code? Any security issue? SQL Injection?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is enough for SQL Injection. Just make sure that you have an active DB connection for it to work.

Comment: What you mean by active DB connection? I have a database connection inside the constructor of my main class. Is that only required?

Comment: Yeah that's fine. By active connection I meant that you should be connected to the DB to be able to use mysql_real_escape_string(); If you don't have it, then it won't work for you and instead, will give an error.

Comment: Yes i have already. So i think there wont be some serious issue on my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain character based fields will need to be surrounded by `'` marks, such as:

```
project_notes = '$project_notes',
```

rather than:

```
project_notes = $project_notes,
```

---

And you should investigate the term "SQL injection" to see why it's a bad idea to just shove values entered by the user into your queries. All they have to do is somehow enter something like

`', salary = salary * 1.5, project_notes = 'actual project notes`

into the `$project_notes` text entry box (or whatever you're using) and you're in for some interesting times.

Parameterised queries are much safer.

Comment: i am new in this quotes ;)

Comment: Hi i am using this to enter data to database? Only admin can use these areas? Any issue?

Comment: @Banna360, without knowing the full extent of your setup, I can't really comment other than to say it's something that should be checked out. Even admins can turn on you :-)